# emulator getting slow on each launch

Tags: performance, android-emulator

I am working on API LEVEL 17 supporting back upto 8. I have some network task to perform that I am doing from seperate AsyncTask class. Now the problem is that whenever **I try to launch the application on emulator first time will be fine, but from 2nd onwards my emulator response is slower and gets more slower on successive launch.** after 4-5 launch It installs the app but never starts the activity. Then I have to restart the emulator and it also need a startup after 4-5 launch.

**I have seen in logcat skipped ### screens!!! UI thread might be doing to much work right from the starting of emulator.**
Can anyone tell me what could be going wrong? Thanks in advance!!!

Regards,
*Sourabh*

Answer (score 0):

Your system configuration is less for android api 17 version your app work properly in api level 8 to 10, so you can set api level 8 to 10.

Comment: what is system requirement for api 17.

Answer (score 0):

Surely process of Emulator starting is slow, as lots of threads and process starts-off when emulator starts. Still for better start timing you can download Intel atom emulator from Android SDK Manager, its also available for android api version 17, Also there is option of choosing Snapshot for emulator, which takes less time for start-off.